# How can I detect reaction words in a string?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, string

I'm trying to detect laughing words like "ididihhhhh" and "omg" in a string.

link design regex :

([regexper.com](https://regexper.com/#%5Cb%28%3F%3Am*%28%3F%3Ahm%29%2Bh%3F%7Ch*hm%2Bh%5Bhm%5D*%7Ch*%28%3F%3Aoh%29%2Bo%3F%7Co*oh%2Bo%5Boh%5D*%7Ce*%28%3F%3Abe%29%2Bb%3F%7Cb*be%2Bb%5Bbe%5D*%7C%28%3F%3Ao%2Bm%2B%29%2Bg%2B%7Cm%3Fo%2Bm%2Bg%2B%5Bmg%5D*%7C%28%3F%3Ad%2Bi%2Bh%2B%29%2Bd%2Bh%2B%7Cd%3Fi%2Bh%2B%5Bdih%5D*%29%5Cb))

and online regex : https://regex101.com/r/hRkWuM/1

```py
regex = r"\b(?:m*(?:hm)+h?|h*hm+h[hm]*|h*(?:oh)+o?|o*oh+o[oh]*|e*(?:be)+b?|b*be+b[be]*|(?:o+m+)+g+|m?o+m+g+[mg]*|(?:d+i+h+)+d+h+|d?i+h+[dih]*)\b"
```

Comment: Okay, so... is it not working? Please describe the problem

Comment: I'm not familiar with laughing words like "ididihhhhh", it's probably a cultural specificity, can you add to the question a more extensive list of the words this part `(?:d+i+h+)+d+h+|d?i+h+[dih]*)` is supposed to match?

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/uiRLPS/1